# creating a simple shell my for loop creates a separate process for each word to read in

Tags: c, linux, shell

So I'm trying to build a simple shell, when I execute the code below it treats each loop within the for loop as a separate process and I'm not sure why.

Questions:

1) When I use the for loop to append each word to read in from scanf(), the program treats each word as a separate process. I think it has to do with wait(), but how do I fix that?

2) Then why does it do that?

3) Then when trying to exit I have to type exit for each new child process, is that related to question 1 or is that a separate issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
int  end = 1;
char *argv[100];
char progpath[30];
char *path = "/bin/";
pid_t pid;
int loop = 0;

while(1 && end !=0){ //while process has no error and user did't type exit
  int argc=0;
  printf("user>>> ");    //user input
  scanf("%s",string);
  if(strcmp(string,"exit") == 0){   // exits process when user types "exit"
    end = 0;
    exit(0);
  }

  char *token;
  token = strtok(string," ");
  while(token != NULL){
    argv[argc] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
    argc++;
  }
  argv[argc] = NULL;


  int i;
  for(i = 0; i<argc;i++){
    printf("\n%s\n",argv[i]);
  }

  strcpy(progpath,path);
  strcat(progpath,argv[0]);


  int pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0){
    if(end == 0){
      exit(0);
    }
    else{
      execv(progpath,argv);
      fprintf(stderr, "child could not exicute\n");
    }
  }

  else{
    wait(NULL);
    }
  }
  loop++;



}
return(0);
}
```

here is an example of the output:

```
user>>> ls -l

ls
ages.c.save  Desktop       hlepshell    OperatingSystems   shell
a.out        Documents     infile.txt   OS hw1         shell.c
arrays.c~    Downloads     makefile~    OS hw1 errors.odt  shell.c~
bfgminer     hello.html    Music        Pictures           shell.tar.gz
bin      helpshell     newshell     Public         Templates
classScraper.py  helpshell.c   newshell.c   python_games       Videos
cs235        helpshell.c~  newshell.c~  scheduler.py
user>>> 
-l
child could not exicute
user>>> hello world

hello
child could not exicute
user>>> 
world
child could not exicute
user>>> exit
user>>> exit
user>>> 
world
child could not exicute
user>>> exit
user>>> exit
user>>> exit
*program ends*
```

Comment: Your code logic is very unclear, like `while(1 || end ==0)`, `while(a<(2^loop))`,.....

Comment: sorry, I must of accidentally copied over previous edit, now updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
    scanf("%s",string);
```

you read a *whitespace-delimited* string from the standard input into array `string`.  You later try tokenize that string at whitespace, but there is certain not to be any whitespace in it.  It's just one word, that you ultimately end up treating as a complete command.  Later, you loop back, read the next word, and give it the same treatment.  Your program is doing exactly what you told it to do.

If you want to read a whole line at a time then I recommend `fgets()`, or `getline()`.  The latter is standardized by POSIX since 2008, but is not part of the C standard.